# Counting how many keys that have more than one value in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I have a very long dictionary. A lot of my keys have more than one value. I want to get the number of how many keys that have more than one value to it.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Do you mean a mutidict?

Comment: Show us what you have.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score -1):

I took the dictionary to be d here, 
   '''Let d is the dictionary'''

```
c=0
for o in d:
    if d[o]>1:
        c = c+1
print(c)
```

I think the above code will work